# How to Generate HMAC MD5 In Android?

Tags: android, cryptography

I am new in this Field!I have this Message and Key also i want HMAC MD5 using this two so how it is possible if possible then give some example or sample code of this.The Given link display the overall functionality i want such kind of code.Please help me.

Messgae = POSTuserMon,28Jun201010:18:33GMT7FF4471B-13C0-5A9F-BB7B-7309F1AB7F08

key = d6fc3a4a06ed55d24fecde188aaa9161

Link = http://hash.online-convert.com/md5-generator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the `javax.crypto.Mac` class. Try `Mac.getInstance("HmacMD5");` and then use the `init` method with your key and then use the `update` and `doFinal` methods just as you would with a `MessageDigest` object.

Comment: ok!i have actually implemented this but it gives me message like "No such algorithm found" so if you have implemented or have any sample code then please give me....

Answer (score 5):

Here are working codes.
Generated result is same as Link = http://hash.online-convert.com/md5-generator

```
public String calcHmac(String src) throws Exception {

    String key = "d6fc3a4a06ed55d24fecde188aaa9161";
    Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");
    SecretKeySpec sk = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(),mac.getAlgorithm());  
    mac.init(sk);
    byte[] result = mac.doFinal(src.getBytes());


    return Base64.encodeToString(result ,Base64.URL_SAFE);
}
```