# HMAC-Whirlpool implementation in Android

Tags: android, hmac, message-digest

Has anyone implemented or using Hmac-Whirlpool on Android phone?
I found [whirlpool.java](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/Web-Framework/rife-1.6.1/com/uwyn/rife/tools/Whirlpool.java.htm) on internet but default security provider in Android SDK seems not to have Whirlpool nor Hmac-Whirlpool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android has cut-down version of Bouncy Castle and seems not to allow access to org.bouncycastle.crypto.macs.HMac class, instead javax.crypto.Mac.getInstance(String algorithm) should be used ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3140650/how-to-generate-hmac-md5-in-android)). Again only some MAC algorithms seems to be allowed (I saw "HMAC-SHA512" is working). But if you decide to use SpongyCastle library, you can do this ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6488658/can-i-use-latest-bouncycastle-provider-on-android/6501205#6501205)):

```
        CipherParameters p = new KeyParameter(key.getBytes("UTF-8"));

        WhirlpoolDigest w = new WhirlpoolDigest();
        HMac hm = new HMac(w);
        hm.init(p);
        hm.update(inbytes, 0, inbytes.length);
        byte[] result = new byte[hm.getMacSize()];
        hm.doFinal(result, 0);
```

Including SpongyCastle may be problematic to many becuase it increased app size by 1.84MB in android 2.2. Then only relevant files could be imported into the project:

// interfaces
org.bouncycastle.crypto.CipherParameters
org.bouncycastle.crypto.Digest
org.bouncycastle.crypto.ExtendedDigest
org.bouncycastle.crypto.Mac

// classes
org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.KeyParameter
org.bouncycastle.crypto.digests.WhirlpoolDigest
org.bouncycastle.crypto.macs.HMac
org.bouncycastle.crypto.DataLengthException
org.bouncycastle.crypto.RuntimeCryptoException