# Send HTTP Post Payload with Java

Tags: java, httprequest, payload, grooveshark

I'm trying to connect to the grooveshark API, this is the http request

```
POST URL
http://api.grooveshark.com/ws3.php?sig=f699614eba23b4b528cb830305a9fc77
POST payload
{"method":'addUserFavoriteSong",'parameters":{"songID":30547543},"header": 
{"wsKey":'key","sessionID":'df8fec35811a6b240808563d9f72fa2'}}
```

My question is how can I send this request via Java?

Answer (score 4):

Basically, you can do it with the standard Java API. Check out [`URL`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html), [`URLConnection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html), and maybe [`HttpURLConnection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html). They are in package [`java.net`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/package-summary.html).

As to the API specific signature, try `sStringToHMACMD5` found in [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8396297/android-how-to-create-hmac-md5-string)

**And remember to CHANGE YOUR API KEY, this is very IMPORTANT, since everyone knows it know.**

```
String payload = "{\"method\": \"addUserFavoriteSong\", ....}";
String key = ""; // Your api key.
String sig = sStringToHMACMD5(payload, key);

URL url = new URL("http://api.grooveshark.com/ws3.php?sig=" + sig);
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setDoOutput(true);

connection.connect();

OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os));
pw.write(payload);
pw.close();

InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
String line = null;
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(line);
}
is.close();
String response = sb.toString();
```

Comment: Yes, it can and should be a `String` in this case that we are using `PrintWriter`.

Comment: I did that but got the same error "method not defined", I defined   String data = "{'method': 'addUserFavoriteSong', 'parameters': {'songID': 0}, 'header': {'wsKey': 'key', 'sessionID': 'sessionID'}}";

Comment: Does the API documentation mention anything specific about the HTTP request? Like what the headers should be, e.g. 'Content-Type'?

Comment: BTW, standard JSON data should always use double-quote `"` to denote keys and String literals.

Comment: thanks a lot, replaced ' with \" and don't get than error anymore. But get signature error for:   String data = "{\"method\":\"getArtistSearchResults\",\"parameters\":{\"query\":\"adele\"},\"header\":{\"wsKey\":\"concertboom\",\"sessionID\":\"0\"}}";
  String key = "b07cd9d001e6895956023687e4629f60";
  
  String signature = hash(key, data);

Comment: How is your `hash` method implemented? I found a PHP client from grooveshark's developer website, it must be a Java equivalent version of the `hash_hmac` in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You could look into the [Commons HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) package.

It is fairly straight forward to create `POST`'s, specifically you could copy the code found here: http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/methods/post.html:

```
PostMethod post = new PostMethod( "http://api.grooveshark.com/ws3.php?sig=f699614eba23b4b528cb830305a9fc77" );
NameValuePair[] data = {
    new NameValuePair( "method", "addUserFavoriteSong..." ),
    ...
};
post.setRequestBody(data);
InputStream in = post.getResponseBodyAsStream();
...
```

Cheers,

Comment: PostMethod doesn't exist in HttpClient 4.2.2

Comment: You will note that the link is for the 3.x version. I'm quite sure something similar exists in 4.2.2 and anyway, you are expected to provide some work yourself, given the guidance from others here :-) Cheers